# SharePoint List customized in PowerApps : Automatically change value of dropdown column based on selection in another dropdown

Tags: sharepoint, dropdown, sharepoint-online, powerapps, auto-populate

I’m new to SharePoint and PowerApps, can you help me on this one on how to resolve this issue?

I have my SharePoint list customized through PowerApps.

These are the dropdown columns that were set to automatically change value based on selection of one another.

1. BOG Disposition
2. Encoder’s Disposition

The scenario are the following below.

1. If BOG Disposition is equal to “Return (For Checking)” then the value of Encoder’s Disposition will automatically change to “Awaiting User’s Response” - *This scenario is okay and working fine both for SharePoint and PowerApps but the problem is the second scenario.*
2. Once the value of Encoder’s Disposition was now changed into “User’s Responded”, BOG Disposition must be changed into “Pending”. However, there is an error on formula saying *“This rule creates a circular reference between properties, which is not allowed. A property cannot reference itself or other properties affected by its value”*

I tried resetting the value of BOG Disposition but still not working.